# Uninstalling and Deleting plug-ins from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am uninstalling a plugin named X from eclipse uninstall option.
Now to make a clear approach I went to the eclipse plugins directory and delete the plugin jar file from there.
Now I am trying to reinstall the same plug-in and eclipse prompts an error saying

> An error occurred during the
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust
>   phase. session context
>   was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust,
>   operand=, action=). Error reading
>   signed content. The file
>   "D:\Testing\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\x_1.1.3.jar"
>   does not exist

Now how to resolve the above issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never delete plugins you installed using the Eclipse installer under Help>Install New Software. Now there is directory used to drop in plugins as jars, which I am assuming you used, if so deleting it would result in the desired behavior assuming you shut down eclipse before hand. If not then you need clean your configuration area. In the future when removing go to Help>Install New Software>Already Installed software, there should be a remove once your there. :)

Goodluck.

Comment: if I do above , will I able to delete the contents from plugins folder as I mentioned above

Comment: I do believe you should be able to.

Comment: I tried to delete the plugin from above mentioned step and then under the tab named Installed Software but post that when I deleted the plugins from Plugins folder same error as mentioned above raised.

Comment: You might have corrupted your eclipse, with the previous steps you took.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked :).. I deleted the plugin from plugins dir and then in Help>Install New Software I deleted the installed history as well as all other reference available in the same link , then I was able to install fresh plugin with the same name :)

Comment: @dustyprogrammer Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette

Answer (score 22):

I have similar issue. I deleted those plugins related files from eclipse/plugins and eclipse/features directory. The reason why I did that is because I have already uninstalled the plugins from eclipse but the files remain in both directories. 
I solved it by editing the eclipse/artifact.xml. I search all the artifacts with the id of my plugins and remove them. And I am able to reinstall the plugins again :)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. I don't understand, why equinox is making it so hard for plugin developers ...

Answer (score 4):

As per eclipse documentation

> You should not remove plug-ins from Eclipse. Plug-ins should be
>   installed as features using the Update Manager. The same Update
>   Manager can be used to disable plug-ins by disabling the feature they
>   belong to. Run Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, select the
>   software you no longer want and click Uninstall. (On Macintosh it is
>   Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details.) In older versions,
>   you might need to Run Help > Software Updates > Manage
>   Configuration..., select the feature of interest, and disable it with
>   the task shown in the right window.
>
> When a feature is disabled, all its plug-ins will be disabled also.
>   They are still available on disk, and they can be enabled at any time
>   in the future.
>
> To physically remove the feature and its plug-ins, you will have to
>   manually remove the feature from the eclipse/features directory and
>   its plug-ins from the eclipse/plugins directory. We advise extreme
>   caution here. Remove the wrong ones, and you may have quite some
>   trouble restoring your Eclipse to a stable state. Unless you care a
>   lot about hard disk use, we recommend leaving the plug-ins where they
>   are.
>
> Note that when manually removing plugins as described above, some
>   metadata is still cached by Eclipse, which can lead to problems later
>   on. Running Eclipse with the -clean option can help with that, as it
>   causes Eclipse to clean the cached metadata

Comment: Documentation misses that you also needs to remove all unnecessary artifacts (plugins and features) from artifacts.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks .. I am not sure what action actually fixed the exact problem i had.
I removed the plugin related files from plugins and features folder, removed entries from the artifact.xml file and opened eclipse with -clean option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run eclipse
2. Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
3. Run updates
4. Updates executed successfully